# Python PANDAS: Multi-Column Pivot and Level Swapping

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have an initial dataframe with the following format:

```
store_id,product,sale_ind,total_sold,percentage_sold
1,thing1,sale,30,46.2
1,thing2,no_sale,20,30.7
1,thing3,sale,15,23.1
2,thing4,sale,10,16.7
2,thing3,sale,20,33.3
2,thing2,sale,30,50.0
3,thing3,no_sale,20,50.0
3,thing2,sale,15,37.5
3,thing1,no_sale,5,12.5
```

I have calculated everything I would like but now I am really struggling to reshape this data to the following format:

```
                product
                sale_in
         total_sold percentage_sold
store_id
1,
2,
3,
```

When I try this:

```
df.pivot(index='store_id', columns='product')
```

I get: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`.

Any tips most appreciated!  I am dreading that I might have to do a solution with hierarchical indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `pivot_table` for multi-columns pivot:

```
df.pivot_table(
    index=['store_id'], 
    columns=['product', 'sale_ind'], 
    values=['total_sold', 'percentage_sold']
)
```

[image]

Or in your case, there's no aggregation involved while pivoting, you can use `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
df.set_index(['store_id', 'product', 'sale_ind']).unstack(['product', 'sale_ind'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  pivot_table seems to work but I would ideally like the bottom column level to be the values and for them to be side by side ideally (instead of one section all total_sold and other percentage sold).  Is that possible with a pivot_table based solution?

Comment: You need to column levels and then sort it, like so `df.pivot_table(
    index=['store_id'], 
    columns=['sale_ind', 'product'], 
    values=['total_sold', 'percentage_sold']
).swaplevel(0, 2, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to .swaplevel() !